# Why does the prefix She- appear in only Tehillim, Shir Hashirim, and Koheles?

Tags: hebrew, tanach, tehilim-psalms, kohelet, shir-hashirim

The prefix שֶׁ is very common in Mishnaic and Modern Hebrew, but in Tanakh appear rarely, except in Tehillim, Shir Hashirim, and Koheles, where it is all over the place. Why are these books the only ones where this prefix is common?

Comment: It also shows up in Eicha Yonah Ezra and Divrei Hayamim. Probably a later Hebrew thing. Note all the instances in Tehillim are in the last 30 chapters.

Comment: It also appears in _B'reshis_ 6:3. But that's a hapax legomenon for _Chumash_, I think.

Comment: @msh210 It's certainly a hapax, but not neccesarily the case that the ש is a prefix. Consider the root שגג.

Comment: Hmmmm [Shoftim 7:12](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0707.htm#12) and [Shoftim 8:26](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0708.htm#26). Go figure.

Comment: Quote from my upcoming book on the History of Lashon HaKodesh (Mosaica Press):
> Similarly, academia points to the usage of the letter ש in Song of Songs and Ecclesiastes (a convention quite common in later rabbinic writings) to mean “that” and “of” instead of the Hebrew word asher (אשר) used in earlier books of the Bible. From this, scholars see that those books were written later than the rest of the Bible and so their form of Lashon HaKodesh more closely resembled that of the later rabbinic writings than other books of the Bible do. However, this argument is easily countered in light of...

Comment: ...archeological evidence of Phoenician and Sumerian inscriptions that attest to such usage of the letter ש in Semitic languages at an earlier period. Such usage is even found in the Mesha Stele (an early inscription), which dispels the notion that these books were only written later. See also M. Boda, T. Longman, & C. Rata (eds.), "The Grammar of שׁ and אשׁר in Qohelet", The Words of the Wise Are like Goads: Engaging Qohelet in the 21st Century (Winona Lake, Indiana: Eisenbrauns, 2013) pgs. 283–307 and Barzilai, pgs. 275–276; 287.

Comment: @DoubleAA, "necessarily"? Perhaps not. But _Rashi_ and ibn Ezra call it a prefix. (And I meant that the prefix is a hapax (I think), not that the word is.)

Comment: The article that @RebChaimHaQoton cites to is illuminating: http://www.academia.edu/4055983/The_Grammar_of_and_in_Qohelet

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that "she-" dates to Shelomo's day or so. In Shofetim, we have "sha-", and in the chumash we have only the full "asher".

What people who think these books were written in a different sequnce than mesorash asserts does with this data point is beyond me.

Comment: @MichaBerger Why is it pretty clear just because there is one possible instance of a slight variant in a highly poetic passage in Shoftim? That's basically the weakest possible support for its usage.

Comment: @DoubleAA: ... and the prefix isn't used at all in Chumash. So there is /some/ kind of evolution from Moshe's day to Shelomo's. The fact that the one occurrence during that transition period is a third form is interesting, whether or not it is enough of a sample-size to be significant as a proof.

Answer (score 2):

The relative pronoun -שֶׁ occurs in Deborah’s Song, in the story of  Gideon, and in the Israelite sections of  the Book of Kings. Consequently, the form -שֶׁ probably replaced אֲשֶׁר in Hebrew dialects of North Israel. The form became standard in Late Biblical Hebrew and Rabbinic Hebrew.

See Blau's *Phonology and Morphology of Biblical Hebrew*, pg. 183.